# Filter questions by interesting tag using "OR" logic

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

Go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions and add "C#" and ".NET" to questions tagged.  This action returns questions with both tags in them.  I would like to be able to filter by either tag (or logic).

Is this a user error or new feature request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to automatically join interesting tag searches with OR operator. Since I only have two interesting tags for explicitly this purpose, I would enjoy such a feature.

For now, you can still do it manually through the URL. Example for you to use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+OR+.net

Comment: You are entirely too quick on the draw. Or else I'm too slow, but I'm going with the first one.

Comment: @mmyers Having the URL active in another tab helped.

Comment: URL thing is pretty cool thanks.  I hope this feature is added sometime soon.